# Is "their themselves" a mispronounce or an idiomatic usage? Does "their themselves" emphasize something over just "themselves"?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/ok_r-mody8w?t=65) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> And the woman said, "Come teach my kids how to clean their rooms and clean up after **their themselves**."

I searched "their themselves" on [google](https://www.google.com/search?authuser=0&bih=613&biw=1280&hl=en-GB&ei=6xVBXs7RHYOo9QPpiJ9A&q=%22their%20themselves%22&oq=%22their%20themselves%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30l4.143995.144790..145129...0.5..0.199.536.0j3......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71.p9cX_MLR_iE&ved=0ahUKEwiO8-GFysbnAhUDVH0KHWnEBwgQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) and [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=their%20themselves), and didn't find an explanation.

Is "their themselves" a mispronounce or a idiomatic usage?

Does "their themselves" emphasize something over just "themselves"?

Comment: I think you've misheard here: she just says "how to clean their rooms and clean up after themselves."

Comment: @Katy Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? 
I'll accept it.

Comment: You're hearing wrong. She simply says "after themselves". American accents do tend to elongate the UR sound (at the end of 'after'), which may be what is throwing you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a fallacy.

Comment: Just to point out, the English captions on the video do interpret the audio as "their themselves" and are probably what caused the confusion.